# MoveIt task constructor custom stages

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I want to create a custom stage to be able to pick/place object with dual arms. I found that is it possible to do so as TAMS-group created a stage to pour (https://github.com/TAMS-Group/mtc_pour/blob/master/src/pour_into.cpp). I also looked at the primitive stages like "pick" but I can't manage to understand what are the essential function that need to be implemented in order to work well with other stages.

And also to better understand how stages work : how does the pick stage interface with movegroup low level function pick ?(is the stage completly replacing the movegroup pick function ?)

And finally is there tutorials on how to create custom stages for MTC ?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351997/moveit-task-constructor-custom-stages/) by [Madcreator](https://answers.ros.org/users/51269/madcreator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2020-05-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Documentation-wise our presentation at ROSCon 2018 is probably a good starting point: https://roscon.ros.org/2018/
It also walks you (briefly) through the C++ API that you need to implement for a custom stage.

"pick" is definitely no "primitive" stage! The current pick implementation is a container comprised of quite a number of primitive stages. Thinking otherwise is very confusing indeed.

For pick/place with dual-arms you will have to setup your own container, possibly using some custom primitive stages to generate paired pick poses, etc.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2020-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Madcreator](https://answers.ros.org/users/51269/madcreator/) on 2020-05-12**:
Thank you for the precision, I watched a second time the Roscon presentation and I understand some new things ! When I was saying primitive stage, I was meaning "default ones" (like simple_grasp, connect, etc.) that exist now in moveit task constructor, I used the wrong word, sorry.
I have already some functions that take a planning scene, plan the dual arm action (pick or place) then return a modified planning scene and trajectories, so I think this will fits well in the "compute" function of my custom stage, am I wrong ?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-05-12**:
I would add that this will probably be easiest if (or maybe impossible unless) you define a planning group that contains both arms.

**Comment by [Madcreator](https://answers.ros.org/users/51269/madcreator/) on 2020-05-26**:
I went further by understanding that I need to also create a specific planner for my dual arm goals. I see in the pipeline planner that is already implemented, that you use the generatePlan (to generate trajectories) function which is also used in the last stage of the (now unused) pick and place pipeline (that is used in my dual arm project), at the last stage : plan. But how are implemented the reachable and valid pose filte and the approach and translate stage in MTC? Is it done by wrappers ?